# Bulk load data conversion error (truncation) for row 1, column 14 (created)

Tags: sql, sql-server, bulkinsert, truncation

Need help please!

I have a SQL Server table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[WSaccount]
(
    [id] [varchar](21) NOT NULL,
    [account_category] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [account_code] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [account_number] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [account_sub_code] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [balance] [varchar](24) NULL,
    [creator] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [open_date] [varchar](25) NULL,
    [product_code] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [status] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [suffix] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [vintage] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [product_fk] [varchar](30) NULL,
    [created] [varchar](25) NULL,
    [last_update] [varchar](26) NULL
)
```

I'm executing this "BULK INSERT" statement:

```
BULK INSERT WSaccount
FROM 'G:\SymitarDrop\BottomLineDrop\account.csv' 
WITH (FIELDTERMINATOR = '","', ROWTERMINATOR = '0x0a');
```

But I get the error:

> Msg 4863, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
> Bulk load data conversion error (truncation) for row 1, column 14 (created).

Here is a sample of the account.csv file (note: there is a "LF" at the end of each record):

```
1,"dem_dep","6","0000337521","","","CORE","2021-02-24","6","PARTIAL_SETUP","10","EXISTING","1","2021-02-24 14:33:42","2021-02-24 14:33:42"
```

I'm racking my brain on this.  Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Specify `FORMAT='CSV'` which handles quoted fields, and  you only have to specify the non-default ROWTERMINATOR.  See docs [BULK INSERT -- FORMAT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/bulk-insert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#input-file-format-options), so:

```
BULK INSERT WSaccount
FROM 'G:\SymitarDrop\BottomLineDrop\account.csv' 
WITH (FORMAT= 'CSV', ROWTERMINATOR = '0x0a');
```

Using `FIELDTERMINATOR = '","'` was a workaround for versions before SQL Server 2017 and is no longer necessary.  And that workaround only works if all your fields are demimited with `"`, which is not the case in your file and is the cause of the error.